# How to fix Google Token service API error?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-platform

I'm building an app with Flutter, Google login, Firebase realtime database.

I've found the database is not connected after an hour after login because the Token service API is not working.

I'm using the below plugins for the firebase.

```yaml
google_sign_in: ^5.2.3
firebase_auth: ^3.3.5
firebase_core: ^1.11.0
firebase_database: ^9.0.6
```

And I enabled Logging to debug this issue in some constructor.

```dart
 _database = FirebaseDatabase.instanceFor(
          app: Firebase.app(),
          databaseURL: _databasesURL,
        );

...

_database.setLoggingEnabled(true);
_database.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

And there are nothing special things. Just I'm using `DatabaseReference.onValue`, `DatabaseReference.update` functions.

I think I did something wrong at the cloud platform. How to fix Token service?

#### LOG

```
D/Persistence( 4874): Persisted user merge in 0ms
D/Persistence( 4874): Transaction completed. Elapsed: 8ms
D/EventRaiser( 4874): Raising 1 event(s)
D/RepoOperation( 4874): Aborting transactions for path: /QGJ11CRtkVaSKAsdomHgVT0Gghs2/search_tap_preferences/excepted_words. Affected: /QGJ11CRtkVaSKAsdomHgVT0Gghs2/search_tap_preferences/excepted_words
D/RepoOperation( 4874): Aborting transactions for path: /QGJ11CRtkVaSKAsdomHgVT0Gghs2/search_tap_preferences/my_list_id. Affected: /QGJ11CRtkVaSKAsdomHgVT0Gghs2/search_tap_preferences/my_list_id
D/EventRaiser( 4874): Raising /QGJ11CRtkVaSKAsdomHgVT0Gghs2/search_tap_preferences: VALUE: {selection_method=무작위 뽑기, my_list_id=a14f61e0-8e1e-11ec-b4e5-239623bc0e23}
D/RepoOperation( 4874): Aborting transactions for path: /QGJ11CRtkVaSKAsdomHgVT0Gghs2/search_tap_preferences/selection_method. Affected: /QGJ11CRtkVaSKAsdomHgVT0Gghs2/search_tap_preferences/selection_method
D/EGL_emulation( 4874): app_time_stats: avg=116.29ms min=2.59ms max=1818.17ms count=18
D/PersistentConnection( 4874): pc_0 - Trying to fetch auth token
D/PersistentConnection( 4874): pc_0 - Trying to fetch app check token
W/System  ( 4874): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
D/PersistentConnection( 4874): pc_0 - Error fetching token: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 1 out of 2 underlying tasks failed
D/PersistentConnection( 4874): pc_0 - Scheduling connection attempt
D/ConnectionRetryHelper( 4874): Scheduling retry in 9016ms
D/PersistentConnection( 4874): pc_0 - Trying to fetch auth token
D/PersistentConnection( 4874): pc_0 - Trying to fetch app check token
W/System  ( 4874): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
D/PersistentConnection( 4874): pc_0 - Error fetching token: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 1 out of 2 underlying tasks failed
D/PersistentConnection( 4874): pc_0 - Scheduling connection attempt
D/ConnectionRetryHelper( 4874): Scheduling retry in 22917ms
D/PersistentConnection( 4874): pc_0 - Trying to fetch auth token
D/PersistentConnection( 4874): pc_0 - Trying to fetch app check token
W/System  ( 4874): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
D/PersistentConnection( 4874): pc_0 - Error fetching token: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 1 out of 2 underlying tasks failed
D/PersistentConnection( 4874): pc_0 - Scheduling connection attempt
D/ConnectionRetryHelper( 4874): Scheduling retry in 15233ms
D/PersistentConnection( 4874): pc_0 - Trying to fetch auth token
D/PersistentConnection( 4874): pc_0 - Trying to fetch app check token
W/System  ( 4874): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
D/PersistentConnection( 4874): pc_0 - Error fetching token: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 1 out of 2 underlying tasks failed
D/PersistentConnection( 4874): pc_0 - Scheduling connection attempt
D/ConnectionRetryHelper( 4874): Scheduling retry in 29761ms
```

#### API ERROR SCREENSHOT

[image]

Comment: Well, I've solved this problem by recreating Firebase Project.

Comment: If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and up-voting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ MaNDOOoo mentioned this issue can be resolved by recreating the Firebase project some times.

In some other scenarios the following solutions can resolve the issue.

-If there is any error in the token service API. This may be solved by
following below steps:

1. Go to [URL](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials)
2. Click on the API key
3. Enable the "Token Service API" with "Identity Toolkit API"

-Can refer to [github link](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/2351) to enable Anonymous Sign-in in Firebase Console if required.